# Debugging hard-to-find exceptions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

First of all, thank you for taking the time to view my question and help. I noticed that a lot of questioners here show little or no appreciation, but I'm sincerely appreciative for the help and the community here :)

I wrote a C++ plugin (compromised of hundreds of source files) for an application I do not have the source code for (it's a video game). In other words, I only have the source code for my plugin, but not the game. Now, somewhere in those thousands of lines in my plugin, something causes the game engine to throw (probably an access violation) and I don't know where. By the time the debugger breaks, the stack is corrupted and all I get are hex addresses for DLLs I do not have the source for (but the exception occurs in my DLL for sure). I tried everything... I just can't seem to find where the exception occurs. Sometimes the debugger points to a "memory relocation" function (which I never used in my plugin), sometimes it points to the engine's GameFrame(), and other times it points to a damage callback (all these are just different member functions of a class).

I tried practically everything... I googled for hours trying to find out how to use other debuggers like WinDbg and Microsoft Application Verifier. I tried to comment out one or the other, or both, where the debugger points, but it still crashes. I even inserted `OUTPUT("The name of the last executed function is: %s", __FUNCTION__)` into EVERY function in my application hoping to painstakingly catch the last function but it seems any kind of I/O prevents the exception from occurring for some reason... And 10 minutes of debugging and the crash happens at some random last executed function.

I can't find out where this access violation is happening or where some temporary object is removed to cause these bad pointers (I check every pointer before using it), but damn, I'm reaching my limit's end here.

So, how does one debug the impossible... a random crash with a crappy debugger call stack? Thanks in advance for your patient and kind help!

Comment: Do you have unit-tests for the various parts/modules of your plug-in?

Comment: If the stack doesn't look right in the debugger then that's a clue that you may be corrupting it somewhere.  I'd look for out of bounds array accesses and buffer overflows in that case.  Sometimes all you can do is divide and conquer.  Stub out functions in your code where you can and see if that makes the issue go away, then add them back in one at a time until it crashes and hopefully the last thing you added is the problem.

Comment: jogojapan: I can reproduce the bug. The problem is, there's no relevant portion of my code that has to do with the game action.

RetiredNinja: I have thousands of functions that rely on each other... That's gonna be hard :\

Comment: In gdb, have you tried `catch throw` to break at the location where the exception is thrown?

Comment: what platform does the game run on?

Comment: Mr. Vallentin: I have not yet tried GDB... I'll look into that, thanks. Mr. Shemirani: Windows

Comment: I think @RetiredNinja is spot on.  Memory stomp. I don't know much about what dynamic analysis debugging tools are available for windows but a tool like that would be invaluable to catch a memory stomp.  Or maybe There is a previous version you can go back to where it works and review what code has changed?  Good luck!

Comment: Aha success, I've at last rooted out the function causing the problem. Thank you everybody for your excellent tips and continuous support. Wouldn't have gone anywhere w/o you guys :D

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: try different debuggers (non MS), they catch different things.
My experience: a program I have source code and full debugging symbols corrupt the stack, VS nor WinDbg can help but Ollydbg comments a non-string var with the value "r for pattern.", so I had overwrote some string buffer onto this var. Also Ollydbg have option to walk the stack the hard way (not using dbghelp.dll)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the old adage "Prevention is better than cure" is very relevant. It is best to prevent the bugs from creeping in, by following good software development practices (unit tests, regressions, code review, etc.) than to work it out later once the bugs show up.

Of course, real world is not perfect, and bugs do show up. To debug memory corruption, you have some nice tools like valgrind, which at least narrow down the problem sections for you to take a closer look at. Debugging a complex program is not easy, and if your debugger throws up, it requires a lot of persistence on your part. One technique I find useful is to selectively enable or disable certain modules, to narrow down the module has the problem.

Sometimes you need to use "referential transparency" to unload some modules. To give you a stripped down example, consider:

```
int foo = factorial(3);
```

If I suspect there's a problem in this code (and the debugger crashes before I can see the call stack), I have to try by removing this code, and see if the problem persists. However, `foo` may be used later, so I cannot just remove it. Instead I can replace it with `int foo = 6;` and continue.

Another important point is to always maintain a trace file, where your code keeps logging what it is doing. When a program crashes, the trace file can often help narrow down the problem. Of course, you disable the tracing by default, so that it doesn't cause a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Nice question, I will update the answer as and when I recall some other techniques I have used. :)

Comment: Although i agree that prevention is better than the cure, it really depends on the system and the scale of the project.  Unit testing or even host simulation can never catch all bugs, especially when working in a multi-threaded and/or embedded system.  Also, logging can and often is deferred to a lower priority task.  If a crash occurs the log will not be reliably up to date.  I would think depending on the game, writing output on the current thread to a file or to screen would be very costly.  Unfortunately, i don't think this answer will help him too much.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've added a printf-like message to every function which outputs the last function executed to the console. It crashes at random irrelevant functions which is why I'm banging my head on the wall trying to find a cure. The game runs on windows and my code is compiled as a DLL.

Comment: @BejanShemirani That is only a part of the answer, and I have mentioned that logging should not be enabled all the time, but only when debugging. The place where I work, logging is _very_ high priority,  and we are not allowed to commit code unless there are sufficient and good log messages. It is really upto each project whether they want to give higher priority to "debug aid" code/techniques or not.

Comment: @BejanShemirani I have also mentioned that good development practices cannot catch all bugs, but I would rather have 10 bugs to handle post-production than 500. Following good practices does help, although it may not solve 100% problems. The usefulness of this answer really varies by situation, and how much you want to take out from it. It is based on things I have found useful several times, but may not be helpful to everyone. :)

Comment: @user1860415 You can still use some of those points, even on Windows. You will have to find a "valgrind-equivalent" tool for Windows and use that. Also, you could try the technique to "unload" modules one at a time, to narrow down the problem. Like I said, debugging complex problems is hard, don't get frustrated by it. :)

Comment: A valgrind equivalent of windows would be WinDbg I think... And thanks for the motivation, it helped :)